# Auto click Google+ share button

Tags: http, https, google-apps-script

I'm looking for a way to auto click the share button in this example link:

`https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DQyVkTxUyFP4&feature=share&source=yt`

Is there a way to do it via http request? Or at least Google scripts?

Comment: you mean auto click by the ignorance of the user?

Comment: Technically speaking, yes. I'm actually designing an approval workflow which includes auto-sharing eventually. So I don't think seeing the share page is practical in my case.

Comment: mmm interesting, I looked over the Internet but I could not find anything :S looks like a security issue. I wonder if you manipulate the true post that the click does..

Comment: Like make an ajax call or something

Comment: Getting the XML is the challenge in that case, and I'm not sure how to get it :S

Comment: Also I am thinking that for the click to happen the user must be loged in to his google account. So the script must be aware of this..

Comment: So there will be no way around to do this by server side. This leaves us with client side only. So what happens if you manage to auto click 50 buttons? each time the popup will apear for auto confirmation?